# R - Using package deSolve, How do I overcome this object error?

Tags: r, ode

I am new to both R and deSolve. I am attempting to solve an equation with the initial parameter and state variable values given. However, at the end there is an error due to my parameters not having objects. How do I overcome this? Do I create a new object for each parameter?

Here is the syntax for the model:

```
myfn <- function(times, y, parms) {

dy <- numeric(6)
dy[1] <- a - b*y[4] - c*y[1]
dy[2] <- y[5]*dy[1]*(1+y[6]) - e*y[2] - (f*y[3]*y[4]*y[1] - g)
dy[3] <- h - i*y[2]
dy[4] <- y[6]*dy[1] - j*y[4] + k*(f*y[3]*y[4]*y[1] - g) + d
dy[5] <- 1.0 - y[5]*(y[1] + y[4] + 1)
dy[6] <- 1.0 - y[6]*(y[1] + 1)

return(list(dy))

}

parms <-c(a= 2.0, b = 0.1, c = 0.1, d = 1.0, e = 1.0, f = 1.0, g = 0.15, h = 1.0, i = 1.0, j = 1.0, k = 0.5)
yini <-c(Y1 = 1, Y2 = 1, Y3 = 1, Y4 = 1, Y5 = 1, Y6 = 1)
times <-seq(1, 60, 1)

out <- ode(y = yini, times = times, func = myfn, parms = parms)
plot(out)
```

Here is the error I am receiving:

```
> out <- ode(y = yini, times = times, func = myfn, parms = parms)
Error in func(time, state, parms, ...) : object 'a' not found
> plot(out)
Error in plot(out) : object 'out' not found
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use `with()`, something like:

```
myfn <- function(times, y, parms) {

   dy <- with(as.list(parms),
       c(a - b*y[4] - c*y[1],
         y[5]*dy[1]*(1+y[6]) - e*y[2] - (f*y[3]*y[4]*y[1] - g),
         h - i*y[2],
         y[6]*dy[1] - j*y[4] + k*(f*y[3]*y[4]*y[1] - g) + d,
         1.0 - y[5]*(y[1] + y[4] + 1),
         1.0 - y[6]*(y[1] + 1)))

   return(list(dy))  
}
```

(Haven't tested this yet -- there may be some brackets in the wrong place.)

If you also name your state vector you can improve readability further by using `with(as.list(c(parms,y)),...` and using state names rather than `y[]`-indexing.